# How to add and remove a relation in a many_to_many association?

Tags: elixir, ecto

So, as per the example in the Ecto docs, I have the following:

```
defmodule Post do
  use Ecto.Schema
  schema "posts" do
    many_to_many :tags, Tag, join_through: "posts_tags"
  end
end
```

and

```
defmodule Tag do
  use Ecto.Schema
  schema "tags" do
    many_to_many :posts, Post, join_through: "posts_tags"
  end
end
```

Now what are the different ways to:

a) Associate an existing post with an existing tag.

b) Disassociate an existing post from a tag.

Note I do not wish to create a nested resource, but rather the situation is I have a `%Post{}` and a `tag_id`, and I wish to either create or destroy an association between them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two ways I can think of which do not require loading all tags for the post:

1. Create a module for the join table, e.g. `PostTag` and then associate/disassociate by creating/deleting a `PostTag` row:

   ```
   # web/models/post_tag.ex
   defmodule PostTag do
     use Ecto.Schema

     @primary_key false
     schema "posts_tags" do
       belongs_to :post, Post
       belongs_to :tag, Tag
     end
   end

   # Create association
   Repo.insert!(%PostTag(post_id: 1, tag_id: 2))

   # Remove association
   Repo.get_by(PostTag, post_id: 1, tag_id: 2) |> Repo.delete!
   ```
2. Use `Repo.insert_all/2` and `Repo.delete_all/2` directly on the `posts_tags` table:

   ```
   # Create assoication
   Repo.insert_all "posts_tags", [%{post_id: 1, tag_id: 2}]

   # Delete association
   Repo.delete_all "posts_tags", [%{post_id: 1, tag_id: 2}]
   ```